# deltaMethod() function not allowing inclusion of dlogis(). Any way to get around this?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I was originally running the following code and it was working great:

```
avg_x1 <- mean(df$x1)
avg_x2 <- mean(df$x2)
avg_x3 <- mean(df$x3)

het_prob <- hetprob(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 | x1, link="probit", data=df)
test <- deltaMethod(het_prob, "dnorm( (Intercept) + avg_x1*x1 + avg_x2*x2 + avg_x3*x3)")
```

I now want to tweak this as follows:

```
avg_x1 <- mean(df$x1)
avg_x2 <- mean(df$x2)
avg_x3 <- mean(df$x3)

het_log <- hetprob(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 | x1, link="logit", data=df)

test <- deltaMethod(het_log , "dlogis( (Intercept) + avg_x1*x1 + avg_x2*x2 + avg_x3*x3)")
```

However, I'm getting the error:

> "Error in D(g., para.names[i]) :
> Function 'dlogis' is not in the derivatives table"

Is there any workaround to replace `dnorm` with `dlogis` in `deltaMethod()`?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Is this `deltaMethod` from the `car` package ...?

Comment: Actually, looks like `hetprob` is from the `Rchoice` package ... ??

Comment: From the error message, you would need to add `dlogis` to the "derivatives table", but that's built in to R, so this isn't easy.  The `nlsr::nlsDeriv()` function allows you to add your own derivatives, but then you'd need to modify `deltaMethod()` (or something it uses) to use `nlsDeriv()` instead of `D()`.

Comment: There's also a `Deriv` package that similarly allows the derivative table to be extended (but `deltaMethod` would still need to be rewritten)

Comment: Yes, deltaMethod is from the car package and hetprob is from the Rchoice package. I can look into the options you mention, thank you!